# Proving $(a,b) = (a{'}, b{'})$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> If $p,q,r,s$ are integers s.t. $ps - qr = \pm 1$, and $a,b,a{'}, b{'}$ are integers such that : $a{'} = pa + qb, b{'} = ra + sb$. Prove that $(a,b) = (a{'}, b{'})$.

The two given equations are : $a{'} = pa + qb, b{'} = ra + sb$. Solving the two equations for $a,b$:

$a = \dfrac {a{'} - qb}{p}$, $b = \dfrac {b{'} - ra}{s}$

I am unable to use the given property of integers ($p,q,r,s$) used to form linear combinations with new values as $a{'}, b{'} $. The reason being that $ps$ and $qr$ are joined by addition operator and not multiplication one, and hence seems to me solving an implausible idea.

Also, the significance of the integers ($p,q,r,s$) having this sort of relation  among themselves is not clear at all to me.

Comment: The significance of the given relation on $(p,q,r,s)$ is that $(p,q) = (r,s) = 1$. At least, that is my immediate guess.

Comment: Thanks, but not clear. Please elaborate. As per my understanding, $ps = 1 + qr$, $ps = -1 + qr$. Translating it to your response is difficult for me.

Comment: $(p,q)$ and $(r,s)$ both necessarily divide $ps-qr = \pm1$. There is only one positive number that does this.

Comment: The first line is clear as there is formed a linear combination, and would result in the value being a multiple (positive or negative) of the $\gcd$. But, the second line of your last comment is incomplete. Also, I hope that the first line refers only to the $lhs$ of the equation $ps - qr = \pm 1$ And then also, as $\gcd \mid 1$, so $\gcd =1$. Your assumption is proved.

Comment: When i say "they both necessarily divide $ps-qr = \pm 1$", I refer to either side of the _equality_ (not equation, although the difference is subtle and not often taught). I refer to the left-hand side to make it clear that they do in fact divide this number, and I refer to the right-hand side to make it clear that this means that both $\gcd$'s are $1$.

Comment: Yes, I was wrong or may be too fast. That applies to both the sides of the equality (sorry, for using the word  'equation' wrongly). Your assumption is proved that $\gcd =1$, i.e. the pairs $p, 1$ and $r,s$ are mutually co-prime.

Comment: You might also want to look at Bezout's lemma (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zout%27s_identity)

Comment: You could usefully solve the equations for $a$ and $b$ in terms of $a'$ and $b'$, rather than the mixed version which is just a rearranged statement of the original equation. Then you might see where the condition comes in.

Comment: Yes, the mutually co-prime pairs of integers used to form the linear combinations can form a new linear combination. And,hence the both terms in $a^{'}, b^{'}$ are again having the same $\gcd$. This obviates the need for any algebraic manipulation (I hope you meant this manipulation to be "rearranged statement of the original equation"), but the book stated this manipulation as a hint! I do not know why? The book stated as hint: "solve the last two equations for a,b". I still hope the book had a reason, but our reasoning can solve it easily anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a number theorist, but I firmly believe that any time you're doing a number theory problem and you feel like dividing, you should multiply instead.  Notice that
\begin{align*}
    a' &= pa + qb &\implies sa' &= psa + qsb \\
    b  &= ra + sb &\implies qb' &= qra + qsb \\
\end{align*}
Subtracting these gives $sa' - qb' = \pm a$.  So $\gcd(a',b')$ divides $a$.  I think this technique can repeated to show $\gcd(a',b') = \gcd(a,b)$.

Comment: I hope that the reason is as given by @Mark Bennet, i.e. avoiding accidental division by zero.

Comment: No, I'm more with Arthur in the first comment to Mark's answer. The integers are not closed under division, so every time you divide integers there is some ambiguity about whether the expression represents an integer or just a rational number.  That's why I eschew it.

Comment: Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2):

The comments are getting too discursive, and I am not sure they are all helpful. You need to rearrange a pair of linear equations in an entirely standard way. This is not the whole story, as there are bits to add, but to eliminate $b$ from the two equations, multiply the first by $s$ and the second by $q$ (always good to multiply if you can as it avoids accidental division by zero). Then subtract.

This gives $$a's-b'q = psa+qsb-qra-qsb$$ and I suggest you take it from there and do the equivalent thing for $a$.

Comment: "(always good to multiply if you can as it avoids accidental division by zero)" Also good to multiply in number theory, for the reason that you don't in general know whether a division goes up evenly, and fractions are non-nice (denominators resist a lot of additive manipulations).

Comment: @Arthur Good point.